# Subqueries with EXISTS

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to select main menu if each of it has submenu in another table. Below is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM main_menu  m WHERE EXIST('select * from menu w where w.main_menu_id = m.main_menu_id')
```

But phpmyadmin gives an error which reads:

```
 #1305 - FUNCTION smartsaf_maxura.EXIST does not exist
```

Can anyone explain what went wrongly here?

Comment: not `EXIST`, it's `EXISTS`.

Comment: @Mippy, I corercted then received this error => #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from menu w where w.main_menu_id = m.main_menu_id') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Just remove the ' in the select

Comment: @Keren, remove single quotes around your subquery.

Comment: don't use quotes in exists . use like this SELECT * FROM main_menu  m WHERE EXISTS(select * from menu w where w.main_menu_id = m.main_menu_id)

Comment: @mitkosoft, thank you..worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shuld work

```
SELECT * FROM main_menu  m WHERE EXISTS(select * from menu w where w.main_menu_id = m.main_menu_id)
```